github action when run " docker stack deploy"
I recently push some codes (irrelevant to my docker/pipeline files), then my pipeline started failing first with an error that suggested docker-compose not found. So I changed my commands to "docker compose". Now I am getting an error which I can't fix.
I am using github actions and docker to deploy my app to my server. Everything runs with no problem up to the last line of my pipeline which produce the following.
Github Action error:
`======CMD======
docker stack deploy --prune --resolve-image=always --with-registry-auth -c /tmp/docker-stack-say-nes-8d71c6835cf0d610df0b49be3291eeeaa0100e4d.yml say-nes
======END======
err: WARNING: Error loading config file: open /home/***/.docker/config.json: permission denied
err: (root) Additional property name is not allowed`

My compose file:
version: '3.6'
services:
  api:
    image: ${CONTAINER_IMAGE:-backend}
    volumes:
      - uploads_volume:/usr/src/app/uploads
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_NAME: sa_dapp
      DB_PASS_FILE: /run/secrets/postgres-password
    secrets:
      - postgres-password
    networks:
      - default
      - traefik-public
    configs:
      - source: nest-config
        target: /usr/src/app/.env
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        order: start-first
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.${ENVIRONMENT} == true
      mode: replicated
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
        - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}-api-http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}-api-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}-api-http.service=${STACK_NAME}-api
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}-api-http.middlewares=https-redirect
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}-api.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}-api.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}-api.service=${STACK_NAME}-api
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}-api.tls=true
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME}-api.tls.certresolver=le
        - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME}-api.loadbalancer.server.port=3000

  db:
    image: postgres:12
    secrets:
      - postgres-password
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: sa_dapp
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/postgres-password
    volumes:
      - postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        order: stop-first
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.${ENVIRONMENT} == true

volumes:
  postgres_volume:
  uploads_volume:

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true

secrets:
  postgres-password:
    name: ${STACK_NAME}-postgres-password
    external: true

configs:
  nest-config:
    name: ${STACK_NAME}.env
    external: true```


changed `docker-compose` to `docker compose`


What runner are you using in your Github Actions workflow?
